# What do you call these scrolling effects and how do I do it in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scroll

I have a client interested in having a website that scrolls similar to this one: https://www.mcaninchcorp.com/

It has the navigation menu on the left and when you scroll it looks like it is changing a slide rather than scrolling down.

The other option is when a page automatically scrolls and stops on the next section like this page: https://www.playup.com.ar/. Just a quick mouse scroll and you are on the next section. Animations are cool to but I am looking more for just the scroll effect.

I have been trying to google these scroll styles but am having no luck. If anyone could just tell me what they are called I can start to look for them in Wordpress themes or how I can program them myself. If anyone has a WP website builder (elementor, wpbakery, divi, etc.) that they know can help me build sites with these options even better.

I appreciate all your help! Thank you!

Comment: Snapping Effect --- [Css scroll-snap-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type)

Comment: They don't seem to be scrolling, in the sense of smoothly moving, just jumping straight to a section on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML/CSS the website uses a library called [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) which has been converted into a wordpress plugin which you could use. Below is an example of the page load transitions for left hand entry, if you wanted to start working out how to implement a similiar effect yourself.

```
    -ms-transition: transform ease-in-out 3s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out 3s;
    transition: transform ease-in-out 3s;
    -ms-transform: skewX(-28deg) translateX(50%);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-28deg) translateX(50%);
    transform: skewX(-28deg) translateX(50%);
```